# Separation of convex sets in finite dimensionale space

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I’m trying to proof that if $A$ and $B$ are two convex sets in a **finite dimensional** vector space $V$, with $A\cap B= \emptyset $ , than there exists an hyperplane that separates $A$ and $B$, but I’m not understanding how to proceed. Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: What happens when  $A=B$? Read Rudin's FA for separation of disjoint convex sets in finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: I edited the question with the condition that the sets are disjoint.

Comment: Theorem 5.3 says that any two convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with disjoint interiors *can* be separated. In particular, disjoint convex sets can be separated. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am a bit confused also because if $A = B$ is a nonempty convex set with empty interior, it is not possible to separate $A$ and $B$ even though part (a) of Theorem 5.3 says it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the case that $A$ and $B$ are both compact -- this makes the proof much easier. Simply take $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $\lVert a - b \rVert$ is minimized, and then show that the hyperplane bisecting the line segment between $a$ and $b$ works.

---

For the general case, use a compact exhaustion argument. Write $A = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ and $B = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} B_i$ as increasing unions of compact convex sets. For each $i$, pick a hyperplane $H_i = \{x \in V : x \cdot v_i = c_i\}$ separating $A_i$ and $B_i$ (here $\cdot$ denotes some fixed inner product on $V$, $c_i$ is some real number, and $v_i$ is some unit vector). Then use compactness of the unit sphere in $V$ to choose a subsequence where the $v_i$'s converge. Then show that there is some $c$ such that $H := \{x \in V : x \cdot \lim_i v_i = c\}$ separates $A$ from $B$.

Comment: Prove that **any** convex set is a countable union of compact convex sets.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: A convex set need not even be  a Borel set. Take the closed unit disk in the plane and remove non-Borel  subset of the boundary.

Comment: @Shiva This answer is wrong and misleading.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks, that's a good point. I suppose instead the general case should go by separating (non-strictly) the closures of $A$ and $B$, then showing that this is a (strict) separation of $A$ and $B$?